# How to make these three images to have the same height and width?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am a begginer using Bootstrap 4 here, and I have these images inside a card, and I am looking forward to make them to have the same height and width, but I am not sure which div should I input an attribute to make it work... Can someone help it? I copied the html code below the image!

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <img class="card-img-top img-responsive" src="https://images.autotrader.com/scaler/620/420/cms/content/articles/oversteer/2017/02-feb/02-24/262253.jpg">
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <img class="card-img-top img-responsive" src="https://lonestarforklift.com/images/default-source/overview-images/hyundai-80d-9.jpg?sfvrsn=b356117d_0">
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <img class="card-img-top img-responsive" src="https://www.wagehourinsights.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/697/2014/06/cars-1.jpg">
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: How to make them equal in height and width?]

Thank you all for the attention!

Comment: Please post a snippet that can be run and modified.

Comment: Do you want to crop them or squish/stretch them?

Comment: try simply putting width="number" and height="number" on the <img /> tags.

Comment: Your images have different aspect ratios (rectangles vs squares), if you hard code a width and height (like @nstanard suggests) some will become skewed. You could try replacing the `<img>` tags with `<div>`'s, set a height for the diiv then set the `background-image` to the path of the image and set `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not have all images to have same width and height always
but you can limit the image dimensions so your UI wont look bad

just add below code and see

```
.card-body .img-responsive{
   max-height: 300px; // you can adjust this height as you want
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you! It really helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `<img>` with a `<div>` and style it like below with `background-size: cover;` property/value. If you are concerned about it cropping the images then simply change `background-size` value to `contain`. If you need the `<img>` tag present for ADA or web crawler reasons then just nest the `<img>` in the `<div>` and hide via styles.

```css
.img {
  height: 150px; /*you can adjust this height as you want*/
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://images.autotrader.com/scaler/620/420/cms/content/articles/oversteer/2017/02-feb/02-24/262253.jpg);"></div>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://lonestarforklift.com/images/default-source/overview-images/hyundai-80d-9.jpg?sfvrsn=b356117d_0);"></div>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://www.wagehourinsights.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/697/2014/06/cars-1.jpg);"></div>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```